# Where can I find info about possible parameters to put in config in a json connector file?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

What are the possible parameters to be passed on a config of json connector file?

Where can i find info for create my own json connectors files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only properties that are valid for all connectors (not the workers) include following

- `name`
- `connector.class`
- `key` / `value` `.converter`
- `tasks.max`
- (among others)

Section - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs

Scroll down to see differences in worker configs and source/sink properties

Beyond that, each `connector.class` has its own possible configuration values that **should** be documented elsewhere. For example, Confluent Hub links to specific connector property pages if you are searching in there.

If you are trying to create your own Connector, then you would have a `configure` method where the properties are defined

Comment: Thanks alot, i didn't understand about the configure method that you mentioned, it's the same config propertie that is putted in the json file to create connectors?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The `ConfigDef` class accepts a string/type that would be parsed from the connector properties file, yes

Comment: i mean, the config property in the json file of the connector, like:  

"name": "connectorName",  
"config":{  
    "connector.class": "JdbcSinkConnector"  
}

Comment: The docs for the JDBC Sink properties are here https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html